# Retrieving mobile contacts are displaying twice in the application

Tags: android, contacts

i am retriving mobile contact data to my app using ListView but data display two time in the List. help me how to Control of displaying contact two times.
I Refered and many solution through web , yet i am not able to sove.
i attached code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter ma ;
Button select;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }else {
        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
    select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

            {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                    checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ma.toggle(arg2);
}

public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY);

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber +" >> "+ name);

        name1.add(name);
        phno1.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    phones.close();
}
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView tv1,tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
        tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
        cb.setTag(position);
        cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        System.out.println("hello...........");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
}}
```

my output :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because storage is returning the contacts twice ,they'll be duplicated because of google contacts,so when you retrieve just put a condition to exclude contacts which are already in.

```
public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY);

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
         if(!phno1.contains(phoneNumber)) { // check wether contact already exists
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
         }
    }
    phones.close();
}
```